# Como cuento valores null en mysql

Tags: mysql

> Esta es mi tabla de mysql

```
CREATE TABLE ingreso_salida_visitante (
                ingreso_salida_vi INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                fecha DATE,
                hora_ingreso VARCHAR(100),
                hora_salida VARCHAR(100),
                motivo VARCHAR(100),
                PRIMARY KEY (ingreso_salida_vi)
);
```

> estoy haciendo esta consulta pero no me funciona

```
SELECT COUNT(hora_salida) AS conteo FROM ingreso_salida_visitante WHERE hora_salida is NULl;
```

Comment: Y hay valores null en tu tabla?

Comment: sii al momento de registrar registro todos los campos pero no la hora de salida

Comment: Creo que podrías hacer esto: `SELECT COUNT(1) AS conteo FROM ingreso_salida_visitante WHERE hora_salida is NULl;`

Comment: @JackNavaRow el group by es innecesario en este caso

Comment: Tal vez estes confundiendo el valor NULL con un valor vacio '' (empty)

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Precisamente la diferencia entre `COUNT(hora_salida)` y `COUNT(*)` es:

- la primera opción cuenta los valores no nulos del campo `hora_salida`
- la segunda opción cuenta los registros que eventualmente cumplan la condición del `WHERE`

Sustituye `hora_salida` por un asterisco (`*`) y obtendrás el resultado que esperas.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo 
  FROM ingreso_salida_visitante 
  WHERE hora_salida is NULL;
```

Aporto un dataset muy simple para ilustrarlo:

```
CREATE TABLE prueba(
  campo1 int,
  campo2 int
  );

INSERT INTO prueba (campo1, campo2) VALUES
  (NULL,1),
  (NULL,2),
  (1,1),
  (2,1),
  (NULL,3);

SELECT COUNT(*) todos,
  COUNT(campo1) no_nulos
  FROM prueba;
```

El resultado obtenido será:

> 5 2

Comment: Acabo de fijarme en el comentario de @PatricioMoracho, muy buena idea contar el campo 1 que es clave principal, claro...

Answer (score 0):

Estas contando los campos sobre los mismos en los cuales estas haciendo la condición WHERE; count(*) o count(otro campo del la tabla que no sea la condición) deberían resolver tu problema.

saludos.